# Laravel 5 - Localization not working

Tags: php, localization, laravel-5

I tried to localization my application, but seems like I'm missing something.
Here is my routes.php

```
Route::get('dil/{dil}', 'CoreController@languageChoose');
```

And here is my CoreController.php

```
    <?php namespace Secret\Http\Controllers;

    use Auth;
    use Session;
    use Input;
    use Redirect;

class CoreController extends Controller {

    public function languageChoose($dil)
    {
        Session::set('locale', $dil);
        return Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

I'm using

```
{{ Config::get('app.locale') }}
```

on my blade so I can show which language is current. But it always says "tr" which is the default language has choosen by me on config/app.php.
What am I missing? 
I'm trying to change language by "app.foo/dil/en"

Comment: Laravel 5 had changed a lot from 4. Please follow this tutorial (great Laracast tutorial) https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website

Comment: I can not explain it better then that tutorial :)

Comment: Thank you so much @LeaTano I checked most of the laravel 5 localization examples before open this topic. But this are for route localization etc. I just want to change session language. I'll use same routes for every language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, setting a session item named "locale" doesn't interact in any way with your "app.locale" configuration. So `{{ Config::get('app.locale') }}` will always return your default language.

**Creating a session item :**

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
```

or

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

**Retrieving a session item :**

```
$value = Session::get('key');
```

or

```
$value = session('key');
```

As described in the documentation : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session

Note that if you were willing to edit your config value for "locale" by doing `Config::set('app.locale', $dil)`, the change would not be permanent and you would have to set it again in every new request.